# Is there a way to reverse the order of the y axis in heatmap of plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

So I have

```
hours = [x for x in range(7,18)]
columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    matrixDatos = [[0,1,0,1,0],
                   [0,1,0,1,1],
                   [2,3,2,3,2],
                   [2,3,2,3,3],
                   [4,5,4,5,4],
                   [4,5,4,5,5],
                   [6,7,6,7,6],
                   [6,7,6,7,7],
                   [8,9,8,9,8],
                   [8,9,8,9,8]
                    ]



    table = ff.create_table(matrixDatos)

    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(matrixDatos, x=columns, y=hours, colorscale='Viridis')
```

But it prints the heatmap with the y axis from 18 to 7 is there a way to print it from 7 to 18?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hi I tried the code provided, I was getting an error saying that number of Y-axis (hours) does not equal the number of Z-axis (matrixDatos). So I reduced the range from 7 to 16 for the code to work.

I used the **"autorange"** parameter of the **xaxis object** in **layout object**, to reverse the axis we need to use **"reversed"** parameter.

**Original Code (provided in question) Output:**
[image: plotly heatmap annotated]
**Code Change:**

```
hours = [x for x in range(7,17)]
columns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

matrixDatos = [[0,1,0,1,0],
               [0,1,0,1,1],
               [2,3,2,3,2],
               [2,3,2,3,3],
               [4,5,4,5,4],
               [4,5,4,5,5],
               [6,7,6,7,6],
               [6,7,6,7,7],
               [8,9,8,9,8],
               [8,9,8,9,8]
                ]



table = ff.create_table(matrixDatos)

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(matrixDatos, x=columns, y=hours, colorscale='Viridis')
fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = "reversed"
iplot(fig)
```

**Code Change Output:**
[image: plotly annotated heatmap reversed]

I hope this is what you need.

References:

1. [plotly layout xaxis reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-autorange)

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
```

before showing figure.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, shows the same output :/